# Command or Shift key modifiers always activated

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, adobe-photoshop

Regularly, when I am using Photoshop CC 2018 (mostly), suddenly I got a modifier key which always stays activated. Sometime it is the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, and sometimes <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which make it impossible to work with these kind of applications using modifiers keys intensely the  for almost anything.

The only way is reboot, but even so, I suspect that when I have rebooted and relaunched Adobe Photoshop, the mean bad appends very quickly, so very hard/almost impossible to work.

Here's my configuration:

- MacPro 4,1 (Nehalem) running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- Adobe CC 2018 Suite

Also, I have a Wacom Intuos4 Tablet, (actually with driver *6.3.32-4*), but I got the bug since several previous version of the Wacom Tablet driver, and (surprise) a mouse and a keyboard.

Worth mentioning: the keyboard is actually a Window keyboard, but it didn't need any driver to install. I just got few key not related to Mac function, but even the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F15</kbd> key function work as intended by Apple when using it with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (Sound Up/Down/Mute and Mission Control etc...).

Let me know if you need a EtreCheck Report, (?)  if so I can quickly post a link of my current report.

Comment: I would be really useful to know if you have the same problem with a different keyboard, to rule out hardware problems.

Comment: Hello; Thanks for your answer, I finally found, another mac keyboard (this time) but sadly got the very same bug.... here us the shift key always activated....

Comment: Here is my latest EtreCheck 5.2 Repport, with the new keyboard, hope this help...  https://pastebin.com/ttPxRum8

Comment: Here is what i think is wausing this bug (excerpt from my console log :

Comment: kernel[0]: process Adobe Photoshop [641] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 489950
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[802]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
ReportCrash[802]: Invoking spindump for pid=641 wakeups_rate=150 duration=300 because of excessive wakeups
spindump[538]: Invalid connection: com.apple.coresymbolicationd

Comment: Do you need the photoshop repport crash ? please anyone can help ? thanks...

Comment: hi, I still have this really annoying bug, is there anyone out here, who can/could help me please ? Tell me what you need ? Do I have to make a clean re-install of all my system ? (not even sure it would do the tricks.. so...)

Answer (score 1):

I do experience the [same issue](http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?t=4157). I have spent hours on debugging this issue. As I found it this issue exists for a long time. I don't sure about 6.3.32-4. Wacom support keeps recommending to reinstall the driver. I am also in contact for a RMA. I guess it is a driver issue. The shift click issue is reproducible using Wacom driver 6.3.35-2 and 6.3.36-2 on macOS 10.12 and MacOS 10.14.

**Solution:**
In my case I went back to Wacom driver [**6.3.34-2**](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support/product-support/drivers), which resolves the issue.